# asp.net mvc and azure active directory security group based authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory

I am looking help for ASP.NET MVC application. Which authenticate single tenant azure active directory users and can authorize users using active directory security group. i.e. if user is part of that security group then only allow access to website otherwise access denied.

Active directory authentication can be done by visual studio itself using wizard but not sure how to perform authorization through AAD security group.

P.S. I am new to ASP.NET security

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a user signs into the application, incoming token from Azure AD will contain **group claims**, once you modify the application's manifest appropriately (see the sample application link below for steps). Your application code can then read these claims and make authorization decisions based on them.

Here is a sample application that does authorization based on group claims -

[Authorization in a web app using Azure AD groups & group claims](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims)

[Group claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-id-and-access-tokens#idtokens)

[image]

### ADDITIONAL INFORMATION TO CONSIDER WHEN IMPLEMENTING AUTHORIZATION LOGIC

1. You have specifically asked about Groups, but you should also consider using Application Roles, which can help you implement a Role based authorization logic. Look at Microsoft documentation link [Application Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles). Here is a link to another similar question where I have provided a little more detailed information on both Application Roles and Groups and links to sample code for both.
   [Azure Active Directory Integration with Custom RBAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52398365/azure-active-directory-integration-with-custom-rbac/52401612#52401612)

   Once you understand the usage/purpose of application roles and groups, it's completely possible for you to decide that you want to base your authorization logic on a combination of Roles and Groups information for the signed in user instead of just one.
2. In case when a user is part of many groups (6 or more AFAIK), Azure AD token doesn't send across the "groups" directly as part of token, instead it sends an overage indicator and then you can query the groups in a separate call. Take a look at the token related documentation here - [Claims in id_tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-id-and-access-tokens#claims-in-idtokens)

[image]

Comment: The token will contain group ids *if* the application indicates it wants them in the manifest. Remember the limit also. Basing security on roles in the app and group-based assignment (if available) is usually the better alternative though.

Comment: Thanks @junnas. I've provided that information in my other answers related to this topic, but it does make sense to add it here as well, just to provide a more complete picture and then the application developer can decide.. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: @juunas I've edited my answer to include that info. Plz feel free to suggest anything else that you see would be relevant.

Comment: hi @RohitSaigal if there is more groups then it contains graph api link which I have to call externally using authorization token.

Comment: Yes @BhavyBhut.. That’s correct.. Plz Look at point 2 in “Additional Information to Consider....” section of my answer for details... that’s what groups overage indicator tells you..

Comment: hi @RohitSaigal if there is more groups then it contains graph api link which I have to call externally using authorization token. Currently I am trying to save token using options.SaveTokens = true; in openidconnection options. But when I am trying to access saved token in custom components. Do you have any idea how to access it in asp.net core 2.1? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.1 see custom components

Comment: @BhavyBhut try looking at the authorization header in current context.. Something like HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Authorization"]