# How to validate if user is part of group in Azure AD?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have written a `Python` application hosted on `Open Shift`.

After user login into application his privileges are decided based on his  group membership in `Azure Active Directory`.

How can I validate if  user is part of a group in `Azure Active Directory` through my application ?

Comment: Hello Hemanth, I have changed formatting of your post so it is more readable. I see that your a new. Just for information. To create a new sentence or paragraph, you must put an empty new line between paragraph. The question is then more readable. It is also a good technic to use ` character to highligh private name. You can edit your question to see what I have done.

Answer (score 15):

You can call the following Microsoft Graph APIs from your application depending on your scenario -

1. **[Check member groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryobject-checkmembergroups?view=graph-rest-1.0)**

   This one will be helpful if you already know the groups that you want to check/validate membership in.

   ```
    POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/checkMemberGroups
   ```

   In request body, you can provide `groupdIds`, i.e. a collection that contains the object IDs of the groups in which to check membership. Up to 20 groups may be specified.

   ```
    {
     "groupIds": [
          "fee2c45b-915a-4a64b130f4eb9e75525e",
          "4fe90ae065a-478b9400e0a0e1cbd540"
      ]
    }
   ```
2. [**user: getMemberGroups**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-getmembergroups?view=graph-rest-1.0)

   This one will be helpful if you don't already know the group and want to get all the groups that this user belongs to.

   ```
    POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/getMemberGroups
   ```

You can also enable group claims to come in as part of the access token for your application by editing your application's manifest (this can be done directly in Azure Portal) and setting `"groupMembershipClaims"` property to `"All"` or `"SecurityGroup"` as needed.

There is a catch with groupMemembershipClaims though, that token doesn't always come with all the groups that user is member of. In case a user is member of too many groups (AFAIK it's 6 or more), you only get back an overage indicator claim like `hasGroups` telling you that user is part of many groups and you should call graph api to get the list of all groups. That's the reason I've highlighted the relevant Microsoft Graph API.

Here is a sample application that does authorization based on group claims. It's using .NET 4.5 MVC, C# but concepts are same -

[Authorization in a web app using Azure AD groups & group claims](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims)

Here is another [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52469913/asp-net-mvc-and-azure-active-directory-security-group-based-authorization), where a similar requirement is discussed. It also mentions considering Application Roles to make authorization decisions, as that can be more appropriate in some cases.

Comment: Since this request is specific to python, could the Azure AD Python-specific instructions modify the example above? The reference given is for .net above, here is the python example provided by Microsoft.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapi-azurefunctions