# How to check if a user is in an AD group via Azure AD?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

**Setup Specifications**

- .NET 4.5.1 MVC Project
- Project contains .aspx files (legacy)
- Currently user Azure AD for authentication via Cookies.
- Azure portal configured (via App Registrations) with "Implicit Grant - ID Tokens" and "Accounts in this organizational directory only"
- On-Premise AD groups are pushed up to Azure AD.

**Startup.cs Configuration**

```
// COOKIES: Tells it to use cookies for authentication.
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
});

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = ClientID,
    Authority = Authority,
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = PostLogoutRedirectUri,
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
    {
        AuthenticationFailed = PrincipalService.OnAzureAuthenticationFailure,
        AuthorizationCodeReceived = (AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification) =>
        {
            var username = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Name.Split('#').LastOrDefault();
            var emailAddress = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Contains("emailaddress"))?.Value;
            Logger.Log(Level.Auth, $"Azure login success! Username: '{username}' Email: '{emailAddress}'.");
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
});
```

**Question**

How can I, given this setup, check if the currently logged in user is in a particular AD Group?

**What I've tried**

All the guides on doing Microsoft Graph API always come up with a problem that I don't know how to get past (e.g. `GetAccountsAsync` returning empty, etc).

I added the following to our app registration manifest:

```
"optionalClaims": {
    "idToken": [
        {
            "name": "email",
            "source": null,
            "essential": true,
            "additionalProperties": []
        },
        {
            "name": "groups",
            "source": null,
            "essential": true,
            "additionalProperties": []
        }
    ],
    "accessToken": [],
    "saml2Token": []
}
```

`email` works fine, but obviously `groups` doesn't as it was a shot in the dark.

Comment: You can also enable group claims to come in as part of the access token for your application by editing your application's manifest (this can be done directly in Azure Portal) and setting `"groupMembershipClaims"` property to `"All"` or `"SecurityGroup"` as needed. Do know that when there is a high number of groups that a user is part of.. you may not get all the groups as part of token, but an overage indicator instead.. and you may need to query for the groups separately in such case

Comment: Okay, so I set"groupMembershipClaims" to "All" and it's returning guids. Is there a way to get it to return the names of the groups?

Comment: Look at this post for more detailed explanations and some other options from Microsoft graph perspective as well.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54149675/how-to-validate-if-user-is-part-of-group-in-azure-ad/54150723#54150723

Comment: Not AFAIK.. you will only get back group Ids as part of claims.. not the group names.. If you're after group names Microsoft Graph API may be your best bet (because that will help with any overage scenarios as well)

Comment: If you're looking to validate whether a user is part of a group or not, you should be using Group Id anyway.. name could always change.. I'm going by your question `How can I, given this setup, check if the currently logged in user is in a particular AD Group?`.. Also, I don't quite follow your issue while working with Microsoft Graph API.. if you can elaborate may be I or someone else is able to help with that

Comment: Yes, I have gotten it working with the Guids. If you'd like you can create an answer with all the helpful points you have made and I'll accept it!

Comment: Glad to know it worked for you.. sure I'll add an answer with these points in a little bit.

Comment: I have added an answer covering our discussion.. Please feel free to mention any extra points you see relevant to make it work for anyone reading this in future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1. Getting Group Membership Claims as part of Token**

You can enable group claims to come in as part of the access token for your application by editing your application's manifest (this can be done directly in Azure Portal) and setting `"groupMembershipClaims"` property to `"All"` or `"SecurityGroup"` as needed.

**2. Group Ids are returned as part of Claims**

Once application manifest is updated as mentioned above, you can get Group Id's as part of claims. Here's a quick sample for a decoded JWT token

[image]

**3. Limit on the number of groups that can be returned as part of token**

To ensure that the token size doesn't exceed HTTP header size limits, Azure AD limits the number of objectIds that it includes in the groups claim. If a user is member of more groups than the overage limit (150 for SAML tokens, 200 for JWT tokens), then Azure AD does not emit the groups claim in the token. Instead, it includes an overage claim in the token that indicates to the application to query the Graph API to retrieve the user's group membership.

**4. Relevant Microsoft Graph APIs**

NOTE: Working with Microsoft Graph APIs can be pretty powerful, since you can get around overage scenarios as well as get all other kinds of information about groups if needed (like name). In this particular case, since intent is to validate group membership, group Id is the best field as it will not change while others like name can.

**[Check member groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryobject-checkmembergroups?view=graph-rest-1.0)**

This one will be helpful if you already know the groups that you want to check/validate membership in.

```
 POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/checkMemberGroups
```

In request body, you can provide `groupdIds`, i.e. a collection that contains the object IDs of the groups in which to check membership. Up to 20 groups may be specified.

```
     {
      "groupIds": [
           "fee2c45b-915a-4a64b130f4eb9e75525e",
           "4fe90ae065a-478b9400e0a0e1cbd540"
       ]
     }
```

[**user: getMemberGroups**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-getmembergroups?view=graph-rest-1.0)

This one will be helpful if you don't already know the group and want to get all the groups that this user belongs to.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/getMemberGroups
```

Here is another [related SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54149675/how-to-validate-if-user-is-part-of-group-in-azure-ad/54150723#54150723)