# Having trouble getting Azure AD user's groups

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, passport.js, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm currently using node.js passport library to authenticate using the OIDC Strategy with an azure registered app using a client ID and secret.

```
http://login.microsoftonline.com/{org id}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

I am not having any trouble getting the user profile back of the person who logged in, but I am hitting a wall when trying to get the groups. In my app, I need to authorize the user based on their active directory groups. I am getting back this piece of json:

```
"_claim_names\":{\"groups\":\"src1\"},\"_claim_sources\":{\"src1\":{\"endpoint\":\"https://graph.windows.net/{org guid}/users/{user guid}/getMemberObjects\"}}
```

I'm not sure what I need to do using this to get the groups. I tried generating a bearer token, passing that in a header, and getting the groups but it says I am unauthorized using Postman. Do I need certain permissions in the app? Also why is it using graph.windows.net when I'm trying to use graph.microsoft.com?

Is there an easier way to do this once the user has logged in?

Comment: I think what you're getting back is an overage claim.. indicating that the user is part of many groups.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVuld.png you can read more about it here.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens

Comment: In terms of what you should do next to get the information about groups for a user.. Microsoft Graph API would be helpful because you will be able to get around overage scenarios that are because of token size.. similar discussion in SO posts here.. **1)** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55288567/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-in-an-ad-group-via-azure-ad/55289376#55289376 and **2)** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54149675/how-to-validate-if-user-is-part-of-group-in-azure-ad/54150723#54150723

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Overage indicator claim when user is member of many groups**

The claim you're getting back as part of json shared in question is an overage indicator claim.

```
"_claim_names\":{\"groups\":\"src1\"},\"_claim_sources\":{\"src1\":{\"endpoint\":\"https://graph.windows.net/{org guid}/users/{user guid}/getMemberObjects\"}}
```

It means that the user is member of many groups and instead of including information about all the groups as part of token (which would make the token too big), you will need to query that information separately.

Read more about it here: [Access Tokens Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#payload-claims)

[image]

**How to get groups information?**

Your application needs to make a separate call to `Microsoft Graph API` to get the groups information for user.

***Relevant Microsoft Graph APIs***

- [user: getMemberObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-getmemberobjects?view=graph-rest-1.0)
- [user: getMemberGroups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-getmembergroups?view=graph-rest-1.0)
- [Check member groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryobject-checkmembergroups?view=graph-rest-1.0)

***Permissions Required by your application***

Each of the API links above mention the required delegated or application permissions that are required as part of documentation.

You will need to update your app registration in Azure AD to require the relevant permissions (and also go through Admin consent, in case the permission required needs admin consent)

[image: app registrations preview experience]

***Token to call Microsoft Graph API***

You mention that you've tried generating a bearer token, passing that in a header, but you got Unauthorized error.

Once you're done with the permission changes for your application, acquire a token specifically for Microsoft Graph API from your application. The bearer token used to access your application may not directly work with Microsoft Graph API.

Also make sure you go through Admin consent in case any of the permissions require Admin consent. If it's a single tenant application, "grant permissions" directly from azure portal by an administrator should work, in case of multi-tenant app you can use the [Admin consent endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#request-the-permissions-from-a-directory-admin).

**Code Sample**: Here is a quick [tutorial for calling Microsoft Graph using Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/node).. you may find other good ones as well.

**Azure AD Graph API (`graph.windows.net`) vs Microsoft Graph API (`graph.microsoft.com`)**

You have a valid question about the endpoint.. "Also why is it using graph.windows.net when I'm trying to use graph.microsoft.com?"

General recommendation is to use the newer Microsoft Graph API, unless the functionality/information you're looking for isn't available with Microsoft Graph and only Azure AD Graph API can help. Read more about recommendation and comparison here: [Microsoft Graph or Azure AD Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/)

Since information about groups is available in v1 endpoint for Microsoft Graph already (not beta), you should make use of Microsoft Graph API.

Here are a couple of related SO posts: [SO Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55288567/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-in-an-ad-group-via-azure-ad?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [SO Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55288567/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-in-an-ad-group-via-azure-ad?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: So once I /authorize, I get a code, I pass the code into /token, and get a token. Then I can use the token to call graph api? Also, I was reading that there is a refresh token, is that something I need to store? I saw it come up once, but I can't get it now and it gives me an error "OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed, please retry with a new valid code or use an existing refresh token" so I'm not sure how to get the token again. Thanks

Comment: Also, what types of scopes am I looking for? I'll check out the code sample

Comment: The issue here is when requesting the groupmembers information through azure oidc the `_claim_sources` returns the old api instead of the new. Its always microsoft thats the issue here. Is there a way to force the new api `graph.microsoft.com` in the token response. this is needed when we cant manually override the host