# Using Azure AD roles of partner organization

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0

In Azure we can invite a guest user from another active directory to your one.

Is it possible to re-use groups from guest active directory?

I don't want to manage it myself. I want a partner organization (what invited guest belongs to) managed them.

**Update:**
I use Azure AD and group in my Web API application, where I can allow access for particular groups via

```
[Authorize(Policy="AdminsOfMyTenant")]
```

attribute

What I want to do is to be able to you in my web api application groups from another tenant.

Assume there's a group "*AdminOfPartnerOrg*" in a partner Azure AD. Then I want to use it like this:

```
 [Authorize(Policy="AdminOfPartnerOrg")]
 class MyWebApiController: ControllerBase
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your case scenario is like below for example:

**Tenant A:**

1. Group Tenant A-1
2. Group Tenant A-2

   1. User Tenant A-1
   2. User Tenant A-2

**Tenant B:**

1. Group Tenant B-1
2. Group Tenant B-2

   1. User Tenant B-1
   2. User Tenant B-2

**Your Expectation:**

If I am not wrong, You want `Group Tenant A-1` member/User could manage `Group Tenant B-1` or Group Tenant B-2 or vice-versa together at the same time.

**Case Explanation:**

Suppose `User Tenant A-1` belong to `Group Tenant A-1`. You want to invited `User Tenant A-1` into `Tenant B`.

But If `User Tenant A-1` login into `Tenant B` , `User Tenant A-1` cannot access `Group Tenant A-1` anymore into `Tenant B`.

On the other hand `User Tenant A-1` can manage `Group Tenant B-1` or `Group Tenant B-2` if `User Tenant A-1` assigned those group.

**Now Consider Your Question "Is it possible to re-use groups from guest active directory?"**

If you wish `User Tenant A-1` sign into either in  `Tenant A` or `Tenant B`  can `Group Tenant A-1` be usable log into `Tenant B`?

No its not possible. in this way. `User Tenant A-1` can manage many different groups. But login into to any specific tenant other tenant group cannot be visible in logged in tenant. Switching between the group it can be possible.

**Note:** `User Tenant A-1` can manage `Group Tenant A-1` , `Group Tenant B-1` separately. But not in single sign in process. He need to switch between the directory.

**Update:**

As per your previous comment you could do it. You can refer this [docs](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2018/02/20/role-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core-with-azure-ad.aspx). Also a slimier explanation you could find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52469913/asp-net-mvc-and-azure-active-directory-security-group-based-authorization)

Once you able to retrieve your group claims after that you could apply `IF` conditional to implement whatever you want. You can refer following [C# Repository.](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims/blob/master/WebApp-GroupClaims-DotNet/Controllers/TasksController.cs)

**Code Example:**

For c# implementation please refer to [this git hub resource](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims)