# ASP.net Mvc 5 - Group policy in authorization from azure AD in MVC5 web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, authorization

I am working in asp.net MVC 5 application Authenticate with external identity provider Azure AD. I want to create authorization with group members. How can I add a group policy in my application? I could found a solution for .net core but not for .net framework.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims/tree/master) that you want. This sample shows how to build an MVC web application that uses Azure AD Groups for authorization. But it is the old one, the newer [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-2-Groups/README.md) is used for ASP.net core.

This is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52470791/13308381) about using Azure AD groups & group claims.

Answer (score 0):

Allow group policy claims in azure [Update manifest file in Azure AD app registraions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims)

Use the custom attributes to check claims.

```
public class ClaimsAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute {
private string claimType;
private string claimValue;

public ClaimsAuthorize(string claimType, string claimValue)
{
  this.claimType = claimType;
  this.claimValue = claimValue;
}

public ClaimsAuthorize()
{
  claimType = "groups";
  claimValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GroupObjectId"];
}

public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
  var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User as ClaimsPrincipal;

  if (user.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
  else
    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
}}
```