# Asp.net MVC form Authentication Application conversion to Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

We have an old application which developed on Asp.net MVC 3 I convert it and update from 4.0 to 4.6 framework things are working pretty good. Just got one more request to convert the application to use Azure Active Directory authentication. We are using form authentication right now.

The issue I am having is the application is so huge, and the application has its custom roles and authentications for every single page.

So what I am trying to achieve register app on the Active directory and when a user opens my application it redirect it to office 360 login, and he can log in there and redirect to the application and return me his email address. After that, I can verify the user and log in it to the application from the backhand code using old form authentication and create session etc.

Comment: The "Wiki" tag here seems inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a starting point, here are a couple of relevant samples that work with ASP.NET MVC web application using Azure AD for Authentication.

Additionaly, to tackle the custom roles that you mention as part of your current application, you could look at using [Application Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles) supported by Azure AD and also Security Groups which is what these samples show.

[Authorization in a web app using Azure AD application roles & role claims](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims#authorization-in-a-web-app-using-azure-ad-application-roles--role-claims)

[Authorization in a web app using Azure AD groups & group claims](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims#authorization-in-a-web-app-using-azure-ad-groups--group-claims)

Here are similar SO posts where I've covered a little bit more detail on the claims and implementation which you may find relevant.

- [SO Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52469913/asp-net-mvc-and-azure-active-directory-security-group-based-authorization/52470791#52470791)
- [SO Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52398365/azure-active-directory-integration-with-custom-rbac/52401612#52401612)

Comment: Thanks for sharing I read these articles. the issue I am having the application have its custom roles which are not linked to active directory as the application was form-based login.

Comment: @Agha I understand. I've seen similar cases of custom roles/authorization logic in legacy applications (not forms based but others).. In most cases you end up having to decide to either change that and use what Azure AD offers (like Application Roles, Groups) OR ELSE if the effort and impact is too much, stick to custom logic for authorization and use Azure AD mostly for authentication. Do take a look at the second sample which uses Groups and Group claims more closely, it tracks the group object ids in application's database and has custom code logic that uses it.. it can give you some hints.